# Unable to run Ansible API with PlayBook class

Tags: python, ansible

When I run a command `ansible-playbook -i /tmp/srv /prov/playbooks/common.yml -vvvv`

I am receiving no errors and my playbook runs on the intended server; however, I run this same playbook through the Python API and my commands return with 'changed' and do not make any changes. However changes are being made when I run the playbook normally.

Has anyone else had this problem? I am currently unable to find any information regarding an issue with the Ansible Python API being unable to install on a remote server.

Comment: You may want to put your solution as an answer.

Comment: @VC1 I've done so. Thank you for letting me know I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that by setting check=True inside of the PlayBook class will run ansible playbooks in a way so that no changes take place on the remote/local server you're connecting to.

I wanted to post this to make sure other people having this problem will be able to find some reprieve from the hours of time I took resolving it.